# Unexpected output using Intl.Collator with Latvian alphabet

Tags: javascript, collator

I need to sort an array of objects by key in Latvian language but when I use Intl.Collator or compareLocale, the output is not correct.

My example:

```
function letterSort(lang, strings) {
  strings.sort(new Intl.Collator(lang).compare);
  return strings;
}
console.log(letterSort('lv', ['ā', 'a', 'ābols','anna']));
// expected output: Array ["a", "anna", "ā", "ābols"]
// actual output: Array ["a", "ā", "ābols", "anna"]
```

Any ideas what can be done?
Thank you!

Comment: Intl sometimes behaves differently based on browser or OS locale settings, so while the sorting might not work correctly on a system set to en-US, it might when switched to lv-LV.

Comment: I can’t speak about the Latvian language specifically, but in the localized collations I’m aware of, diacritical marks only affect sorting order when comparing to the same letter with a different mark (or no mark at all) *in the same location*. You can think of it as if everything was first sorted with all diacriticals removed, and then the order is refined only where the unaccented forms would be identical.

Comment: I just did some experimentation with different locales, and always got the same sort order, even if I used an invalid locale like "xx". It might be that the JavaScript you're using simply doesn't have support for Latvian, and you're getting generic Unicode sorting instead. There doesn't seem to be a JavaScript `Intl` method that will tell you what locales are actually supported, unfortunately.

Comment: here some explanation for this problem could help: http://www.indiscripts.com/post/2010/10/alphabetical-sort-in-javascript-and-indesign

Answer (score 0):

It might be old, but I was also working with Latvian and had the same problem. I got it working like this.

```
const comparer = new Intl.Collator(undeifned, {numeric: true,sensitivity: "variant",}).compare;

function sortByNameAscending(list: List[]): List[] {
  return sort(list).by([{ asc: (u) => u.name[0], comparer }]);
}
```

I had more parameters to sort by, but this is a stripped version of it. You just use the first letter rather than the whole word.

Edit: It will sort the first letters correctly, but it will fall back in the next. (Ceļ, Cel)